# How to use Live Data correctly in my case Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

[HomeFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1cEI.png)
Everything seems to be done correctly, but when you flip the screen, the resulting value from the EditText disappears from the TextView. What to do tell me pls
[HomeViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvY9X.png)
[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zRZp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing wrong is that you start observing the value from the viewmodel only after you click `btnSend`.
This creates two problems. The first is the obvious one you have found already. You lose the value upon rotating because you have a new View.
The second one is that every time you click on btnSend you are re-observing your LiveData with a new observer object.

You have to move the folowing code inside your `OnCreateView` after setting the `binding` value

```
viewModel.myValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    binding.txtResult.text = viewModel.myValue.value
}
```

You can also replace the second part of the assignment with just `it` as it is suggested in the answer from @JustSightseeing

Comment: bruh, I just realized I made a stupid mistake, thanks for the help

Comment: Just to point out, .value of liveData will probably return null, use "it" instead, the rest is good

Comment: I totally agree that `it` should be used instead of `.value` and I have already pointed it out in my answer attributing you @JustSightseeing , but for performance and concurrency reasons, not because it will return null. I would expect it to return the same value as `it` in most if not 100% of the cases, since LiveData are a UIThread beast

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
viewModel.myValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    binding.txtResult.text = viewModel.myValue.value
}
```

with

```
viewModel.myValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    binding.txtResult.text = it
}
```

Comment: Also, you should place the "observer" of the liveData outside the click listener (why would you want start multiple listeners on multiple button click)